# tkinter did not import successfully. Please check your setup

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, import

Been trying for days to figure out why this won't work. I've tried this on 3 different freshly new Linux Mint distros and I get this error every time.

I'm trying to complete step 1 for the GUI tutorial on rasperry pi's website. https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/getting-started-with-guis/

I've simply done the following:

1. Verified Python3 is installed and up to date
2. Installed guizero

> from guizero import App
>
> app = App(title="Hello world")
>
> app.display()

The error message follows attempting to run this file. (Title is complete error message)

**Edit:**

Yes, I am using Python 3. I verified Python 3 is installed and run the script using Python 3. I installed guizero via pip3.

Comment: Are you sure that you are running the code in python3? It's ``Tkiner`` in py2 and ``tkinter`` in py3. Do you run your code with ``python3`` or ``python`` command?

Comment: Yes I am using Python 3

Comment: on python 3.9 Initially I tried the command mentioned in answer, did not work but I tried installing specific version of tk as "sudo apt-get install python3.9-tk and it worked". Note 3.9 in the command.

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter only comes as standard on windows. The default GUI module for Linux is Gtk. Tkinter is available on apt under the name Python-Tk

python3:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```